# DataTable fill Object

Tags: c#, list, object, datatable, fill

I'm coding in C# but there is an error I actually can't solve, maybe can someone help me here!

Sorry for my english, I'm not a native speaker!

Here is my code :

```
public List<Materiel> GetAllTubas()
{
 DataAccess.Oradb getListTubas = new DataAccess.Oradb();
 getListTubas.GetTubaDatabase(null);

 List<Materiel> ListMateriel = new List<Materiel>(); 

 foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)  //the name "dt" does not exist in the current context     {
    var myListTuba = new Materiel();
    myListTuba.Nom = row["nom_tuba"];
    ListMateriel.Add(myListTuba);
 }

 return ListMateriel;
}
```

In this methode I call another method GetTubaDatabase ; connect to database and SQL query, it returns me DataTable dt fill with the result of my query.
Now I would like to create a List thanks to my Datatable, but an error appear : the name "dt" does not exist in the current context (approximately translate from my mothertongue)

I think that's not a huge error but I can't solve it and dunno how I can.

Hope you'll help me !

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Where did you define ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to first assign the return value to a variable:

```
DataTable dt = getListTubas.GetTubaDatabase(null);
```

Then you can use it later in your code. Executing a method does not magically create variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you solved it, but I got another problem and cant reply to this question! Should I create a new one ? I need more reputation, I'm new!

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to assign the data to your datatable probably you should change this line of code

```
var dt = getListTubas.GetTubaDatabase(null);
```

This will populate your data table

Answer (score 0):

You also forgot to do this:

```
 myListTuba.Nom = row["nom_tuba"].ToString();
```

That should do it